# Neutral $B$-meson oscillations

Tags: particle-physics, mesons

I would have a question about an Equation in Mark Thomson's book "Modern Particle Physics".

On page 397, Eq. (14.62), he arrives at

$$\vert B\left( t\right)\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left[ \theta_{+}\vert B^{0}\rangle + \xi\theta_{-}\vert\bar{B}^{0}\rangle\right].$$
He then writes in Eq. (14.65) that $$P\left( B_{t = 0}^{0}\rightarrow B^{0}\right) = \left\vert \left\langle B\left( t\right) \vert B^{0} \right\rangle \right\vert^2 = \frac{1}{4}e^{-\Gamma t}\left| \theta_{+}\right|^2.$$

Unfortunately, it is unclear to me how the factor $e^{-\Gamma t}$ enters, isn't $\left\langle B^{0}\vert B^{0}\right\rangle = 1$? Thank you.

**Edit**: $\theta_{+}$ is given by $2e^{-\Gamma t/2}e^{-iMt}\cos\frac{\Delta m_d t}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product is between the time evolved ket $|B(t)\rangle$ and the flavour eigenstate $|B^0\rangle$. You didn't give enough information about the specific form of the coefficients $\theta_\pm$ but I can guess that they depend on time by a exponentially suppressing factor $e^{-\Gamma t/2}$ so, even given the fact that $\langle B^0|B^0\rangle = 1$, there still remain the *real* time dependence of the coefficients.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. But isn't the real time dependence already in the $\left| \theta_{+}\right|^2$?

Comment: Then yes then probably it's a typo. The result should be $$e^{-\Gamma t}\cos^2(\Delta m_d t/2)$$